# Why aren't my answers shown on my Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: support, answers, profile-page

I love this website.  It's my favorite site, and I use it hourly.  But I'm not smart enough (like most of you) to contribute to the coding questions, the asp.net questions, and so on.  The questions I **AM** qualified to answer such as the ones involving oscommerce or search engine optimization, I've attempted to answer.  I've even gotten an "accepted answer" on one of my answers.

But I believe my answers aren't showing up on my profile, making me look like a leech who has nothing to offer.  For instance:
[Sitemap tool fails to find all URLs in my site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23778/seo-method-does-not-work-with-me/23812#23812)

I answered here, but didn't receive credit for it.  For whatever reason, when answering, I was redirected to webmaster.stackexchange.com -- is that the reason why I'm not getting credit for answers?

I just want people to know that although I'm not the most brilliant out there, I do try to chip in when and where I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get credit on webmasters - either if you already had credit on SO before it was migrated, or as you get votes on your answer after the question has been migrated to webmasters.

You can see your http://webmasters.stackexchange.com profile and reputation points at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/12288/jason-weber.

It sounds like maybe you should be monitoring http://webmasters.stackexchange.com instead of http://stackoverflow.com, if these are the types of questions you are looking to answer.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Ziesemer.  The questions I ask are usually asp.net related, usually about MS Visual Web Developer.  I'm not intelligent enough to answer any programming questions, but questions dealing with oscommerce and search engine optimization, I can offer something.  So I just didn't want to come across as a leech or whatever.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Pardon the terseness, but

[image]

---

> For whatever reason, when answering, I was redirected to webmaster.stackexchange.com -- is that the reason why I'm not getting credit for answers?

Yes. Each Stack Exchange site uses separate user profiles.

Comment: Matt's right, the answers you provide on each network site will only be shown *on that site*. If you want to see *all* your questions and answers, view your profile page on http://stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you @Marr.  I just don't have the smarts to answer questions on stackoverflow.  I ask questions there, usually dealing with Visual Web Developer and asp.net 4.0, and such.  But I don't want people to think I'm some leech who just uses and has nothing to offer.  So when I see a question dealing with SEO or oscommerce, which I actually am qualified to answer, I try to help, and I just wanted others to know that I try to help when I can!   Thanks again for your response.